# Java Spring 5.3 - How to order exception handling with the use of @RestControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot

MY application throws 'UnknownHostException' from RestTemplate and it falls into the exception handler with 'Exception.class' instead of 'UnknownHostException.class'.

When I remove 'Exception.class' handler, then it falls into 'UnknownHostException.class' handler.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleGlobalException(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UnknownHostException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleUnknownHostException(UnknownHostException e, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = ...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually not sure but you could code it `if (e instanceof UnknownHostException)` maybe?

Comment: Please double-check whether the class UnknownHostException thrown by RestTempalte is the same you handle in your ExceptionHandler

Comment: Can you also post your class where error is being thrown or occurring? As mentioned by @M.Mas. , check also what is being thrown by RestTemplate , Also, make sure the handler for `Exception.class` is at the end and more specific Exceptions at the start!